# Get the before and after values of a node field

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I need to compare the **before** save/update value with the **after** save/update value of a node field.

Example: There is an already existing node with the title of "Hello". I then edit the node and change the title to "World".

I need to get the before value of "Hello".

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node){

    $before = $node->title; 
    drupal_set_message($before, 'error');  

}


function mymodule_node_update($node){

    $after = $node->title; 
    drupal_set_message($after, 'warning');  

}
```

But I always keep getting the same value...

[image]

**Did I just discover a drupal bug? or what? Because I've used this method in the past with user hooks and it works as expected:**

```
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {

     $before = $account->field_custom['und'][0]['value'];
     drupal_set_message($before, 'error'); 

}

function mymodule_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {

     $after = $account->field_custom['und'][0]['value'];
     drupal_set_message($after, 'warning');  

}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking... :/

Comment: @JimmyKo Node title is "Hello", I then edit the node and erase the "Hello" and instead put "World" and save node. I need to know the before/deleted value of "Hello".

Comment: I confused about which situation you expect to have because you have 2 cases in the question. :P

Comment: @JimmyKo the 2nd case works as expected, while the 1st case does not.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. I thought the 1st case should be expected. Why there is difference between them?

Comment: @mchar the node already exists, and I keep getting the same value.

Comment: I am thinking the same thing as @mchar.

Comment: @mchar your method worked, can you post your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For new created nodes in [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x) you will never get any old values for any `$node` fields. Use `node_load($node->nid)` to load the previous instance of the `$node` and do any comparisons with it. You can also use `$node->original` to view the commited values to the database.